# Select distinct word count?

Tags: mysql, select, count

I am trying to put together a report that shows what search criteria a user used.

Right now it is basic and uses SELECT DISTINCT and then GROUP BY.

The problem is we would like to see this broken down by words too.  The phrase criteria is useful but we would like to see:

```
Searches:
red apples are good
yellow bananas are bad
bad apples are not bananas
pears are not red

What we would like to see:
red            2
apples         2
are            4
good           1
yellow         1
bananas        2
bad            2
pears          1
not            2
```

I should note too that we have too me search terms to go through and write seperate %LIKE statements for them - and they change.

Comment: @TinTran - sorry that got cut off

Comment: so in the example above you have 4 searches in 4 different rows right?

Comment: Yes and right now they would just show up with the entire string on our current report.

Comment: @logan - everything I have tried gives me an error.

Comment: @blankip : post here your code with error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this example

```
SELECT word,COUNT(*) as count
FROM
(SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(searches,' '),' ',value.v),' ',-1) as word
FROM yourtable,(SELECT 1 as v UNION 
                SELECT 2 UNION 
                SELECT 3 UNION
                SELECT 4 UNION
                SELECT 5)value
 )T
WHERE word != ''
GROUP BY word
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e31c9/8)

Comment: what are you doing with UNION 4 times ?

Comment: UNION 4 times to get different words in the search phrase. your search phrase has maximum of 5 words so that's why the SELECT 1 to SELECT 5 if you have more you need to UNION more like SELECT 6 and SELECT 7 and so on

Comment: He said, its dynamic word., it may have more than 5

Comment: then just add up to the maximum, there has to be maximum defined.

Comment: This script is awesome @TinTran - I can adjust how many words is needed.  I am not google so if someone has 8 terms I can concede.  The only issue I have is commas.  How do I totally get rid of commas above.  For instance "apples" and "apples," are showing different.

Comment: use string replace command

Comment: @logan - I tried to but must have injected it wrong.

Comment: instead of `searches` use use `replace(searches,',',' ')`

Comment: @TinTran - that is one of the best answers I have been given on stack.  I asked the question even though at least 3 similar questions have been asked and none with mysql answers.  I am only parsing about 25,000 searches (intranet site) a month - but it is at less than .7 seconds which means is it not only a viable script but I can leave it as a live view (instead of running a query to create a table).